# JSF 2.0 HTMLCommandButton doesn't call ActionListener in Custom Component

Tags: java, jsf-2, jboss, custom-component

I'm currently developing a PopUp with plain JSF on a JBoss AS 7.1 and I'm trying to add a command button in the renderer of the popup-class. The class Popup extends UIPanel.
The popup is inside a h:form.

The code that adds the button to the popup:

```
private static final String ID_FIELD_TAG = "id";
private static final String HTML_DIV_TAG = "div";
```

[...]

```
writer.startElement(HTML_DIV_TAG, component);
writer.writeAttribute(ID_FIELD_TAG, konstanten.getPopupFooterId(), ID_FIELD_TAG);
writer.write("\n");
if(popup.isShowDialogButtons()){
    HtmlCommandButton cancelButton = new HtmlCommandButton();
    component.getChildren().add(cancelButton);
    cancelButton.setId(konstanten.getPopupFooterCancelButtonId());
    cancelButton.setValue(popup.getCancelText());
    if (!popup.getCancelAction().equals("")) {
        String expression = "#{"+popup.getCancelAction()+"}";
        MethodExpression methodExpression = ExpressionHelper.EXPRESSION_HELPER.
            generateMethodExpression(expression, null,
                new Class<?>[] { ActionEvent.class });
        cancelButton.addActionListener(new MethodExpressionActionListener(
            methodExpression));
    } else {
        cancelButton.setOnclick("hidePopup('" + componentId + "')");
    }
    cancelButton.encodeAll(context);
}
writer.endElement(HTML_DIV_TAG);
```

The button is visible, but nothing happens when clicking it, except for a page-reload.

popup.getCancelAction() returns "NameOfTheBean.NameOfTheMethod".

There are no error Messages.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:
I tried to replace the HTMLCommandButton with a HTMLCommandLink to see, whether the form is the problem or not. The link looks like it's working, but still nothing gets called.

Comment: I changed the method, so it uses a direct ActionListener, which should just print "action", but this also doesn't work. Has nobody an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the buttons were not correctly added to the JSF component tree. I've added them as a child to the component and ignored them in the encodeChildren()-methode.

If somebody knows a better solution I would love to know it, so please don't hesitate to answer to this question!